# how to find out if a node is a parent node using xslt for an xml format dynamically?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery, xslt-2.0

```
<main>

     <p>p1</p>
     <p>p2</p>
     <q>
        <z>z1</z>
        <a>a1</a>
        <b>
           <c>c1</c>
        </b>
     </q>

</main>
```

How do i parse through this xml format using xslt generically so that i find out which node is a parent node , i dont want to use the element name  specifically it should happen on the go ?

i want the output as follows:
z1
a1
c1

only element with child nodes but dynamically

Comment: `//node()[node()]` selects all nodes that have at least a child node.

Comment: "Find out" is an ambiguous description. What do you intend to do with this finding? Show us your expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i have edited the question now

Comment: Your output makes no sense to me. Why is `p1` not included? The `p` elements are leaf nodes just as the `z`, `a` and `q` elements are.

Answer (score 0):

> i want the output as follows: z1 a1 c1
>
> only element with child nodes but dynamically

It seems you want the string value of elements, whose parents are elements that are not the top element of the XML document.

**To produce a sequence of the wanted strings, one way is to use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
/*//*/*/text()[normalize-space()]
```

---

**XSLT-2.0 -based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="/*//*/*/text()[normalize-space()]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<main>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
    <q>
        <z>z1</z>
        <a>a1</a>
        <b>
            <c>c1</c>
        </b>
    </q>
</main>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
z1a1c1
```